# Tables don't render after first click in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, axios, rendering

When i click on nav button then table data loads but on second time click table data doesn't load but  data in loads on every click in react js

I have put the code in `componentdidMount() {}` to load it every time when it loads. i made async function which loads table and also set header.

```
{this.state.numofbugs.map((data)=> {
    return (
        <li key={data}>
            <Link to={'/applogs/' + data}
                     className="waves-effect" className={this.props.location.pathname === '/applogs/' + data ? 'active': ''}>
                <span className="font-size waves-effect" >{data}</span>
            </Link>
        </li>
    )
})}
```

in file where it renders

```
componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.location.pathname.includes('app_')) {
        this.showTable(this.props.location.pathname.split('/')[2]);
    }
}

async showTable(col_name) {
    // empty data
    this.state.logtable = []
    let conf = { headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('session') }}
    Axios.get(links.baseURL + 'sample?collection=' + col_name, conf).then((response) => {
        // get headers
        this.state.tableHeaders = [
            Object.keys(response.data.result[0])[0], 
            Object.keys(response.data.result[0])[1],
            Object.keys(response.data.result[0])[2],
            Object.keys(response.data.result[0])[3],
        ]

        Object.keys(response.data.result).map((key) => {
            this.state.logtable[key] = response.data.result[key];
            this.state.logtable[key]['key'] = key.toString()
        }); 
        this.setState({'logtable': this.state.logtable});
    });
}
```

I expected to get data in my table on every button click in table but after one time click on tab of collapse data laods in table then on second time data loads in tag not table

Comment: Why do you have `this.state.logtable = []` in the beginning of `showTable`? shouldn't be defined in the constructor? Then you are defining `this.state.tableHeaders = ` I don't get your idea of states use. You should mutate the state only with setState, not with `this.state.sometinhg = something`

Comment: showTable(col_name) this function renders only one time not every time, how can i make it render everytime.

Comment: please read this https://medium.com/@kkranthi438/dont-mutate-state-in-react-6b25d5e06f42

Comment: Thanks those solution contribution helped me alot and seeked a great amout of knowledge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, you don't need to empty your state like,

```
this.state.logtable = []
```

If you want to replace your existing state with new one, you can simply set the state with new data.

Another issue is, **you are directly mutating your state**, like this

```
this.state.tableHeaders = [
    Object.keys(response.data.result[0])[0], 
    Object.keys(response.data.result[0])[1],
    Object.keys(response.data.result[0])[2],
    Object.keys(response.data.result[0])[3],
]
```

And this

```
Object.keys(response.data.result).map((key) => {
    this.state.logtable[key] = response.data.result[key];
    this.state.logtable[key]['key'] = key.toString()
});
```

You should make use of local variables to create temporary array, and then need to set them in your state like,

```
async showTable(col_name) {

    let conf = { headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('session') }}
    Axios.get(links.baseURL + 'sample?collection=' + col_name, conf).then((response) => {
        // get headers
        let tableHeaders = Object.keys(response.data.result[0]).map((key,index) => index <=3 && key.toString())

        let logtable = Object.keys(response.data.result).map((key) => ({
            logtable[key] : response.data.result[key];
            logtable[key]['key'] : key.toString()
        })); 
        this.setState({logtable, tableHeaders});
    });
}
```

Comment: yes , thank you very much for the solution. I did this and it worked but when i have to load this in on page load, i am calling API in componentDidMount and it doesn't work on page loading :( @ravibagul91 ,